# Foreach in Controller returns Only one Output Laravel and Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to display names from the database using Ajax and I use foreach loop in the controller but it only returns one name instead of two(it doesn't loop correctly). I have seen some answers, peoples suggested to use foreach in the view but for my case I use Ajax in the view how can I use the foreach in Ajax or is there any way it can display all names?

I have tried using these, but it was returning one name instead of two.

```
$data = [];
$data[] = $review->user->name;
```

Controller

```
  $products = Product::where('id','=',$id)->with('reviews.user')->get();
        foreach ($products as $product)
        {
            foreach ($product->reviews as $review){
                $data =  $review->user->name;
                dd($data); //This returns one name
            }
        }
```

Ajax

```
 <script >
 function userRatingname() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '{{route('userRating.name ', $id)}}',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#userRatingname').html('<div>' + data + '</div>');

        }
    });

}
userRatingname(); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the value of `$data` again and again, so it will away return the last user name.

You need to put the  `$data = [];` out of loop. and use `$data[] = $review->user->name;` inside the loop:

```php
$products = Product::where('id','=',$id)->with('reviews.user')->get();
$data = array(); // defined the $data here out of loop
foreach ($products as $product)
{
   foreach ($product->reviews as $review){
       $data []= $review->user->name; // push the username to $data   
   }
}
// Or you can use whereIn for User:
$data = User::whereIn('id', ProductReview::where('product_id',$id)->pluck('user_id'))->pluck('name')->toArray();

return response()->json(['code' => 200, 'data' => $data]);
```

Change your ajax code:

```js
function userRatingname() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '{{route('userRating.name ', $id)}}',
        success: function(data) {
            var html = '';
            data['data'].forEach(function(name) {
                html += '<div>' + name + '</div>'
            });
            $('#userRatingname').html(html);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried that before and now this is the output `Array:1 [▼
  0 => "Ethan"
]` only one name @TsaiKoga

Comment: @user11710915 are us sure about that product's reviews has more than one user?

Comment: Yeah am sure because the product has two reviews with different users @TsaiKoga

Comment: @user11710915 what about `Review::where('product_id', $id)->pluck('user_id')`, did it  return two user_ids

Comment: yeah `#Items: Array:2 [▼
    0 => 1
    1 => 4
  ]` @TsaiKoga

Comment: @user11710915 can u post the relationship method?

Comment: The thing I just realized is that in this line `foreach ($product->reviews as $review)` if I do dd($product->reviews ) I see the array of two reviews but if I do dd( $review) it shows only one review. @TsaiKoga

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210229/discussion-between-tsaikoga-and-user11710915).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have a problem on displaying the stars with the answer you just provided can you help please? @TsaiKoga

Comment: @user11710915 there is no stars in your code. I think that is the css problem. nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Yeah I mean, I wanted to display name, title and stars(review stars) so I knew that if one gets solved then the other will be easy to solve but now I found is hard to display the ratings using `var html = ''; data['data'].forEach(function(name) {html += '<div>' + name + '</div>';}); $('#userRatingname').html(html);` That is why I was asking if you can help. I have the code is just a loop so I don't know how to connect them. @TsaiKoga

Comment: @user11710915 sorry, i have no idea about the design drawing of your frontend, don't know how to display all those elements. It's beyond the scope of the problem.

Comment: I have the script( is just short script) if you wanna help I can show you because the problem I have is I don't know how I can connect the data I receive from controller to that in view. @TsaiKoga

Comment: @user11710915 I think you'd better add a new question and post the explanations about the stars, title, ... columns and how do u want to display them.

Answer (score 0):

try this one if its right tell me.

```
     $data = [];//define empty array.


    $products = Product::where('id','=',$id)->with('reviews.user')->first();


        foreach ($product->reviews as $review){
            $data[]= [$review->user->name];

        }
```

i understand your issue you are using variable not array so in loop u use array and use[your storing value]

Comment: The output is `Array:1 [▼
  0 => Array:1 [▼
    0 => "Ethan"
  ]
]`     @M.Idrish

Comment: idrishmakda52.im@gmail.com send me your code i will solve your problem

Comment: Can you just solve it here so that it will be helpful for others too. @ M.Idrish

Comment: ok i want to see dd($products = Product::where('id','=',$id)->with('reviews.user')->first()); comment me full output of this dd

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to add the "csrf" tag in your ajax call